# How to select different buildTypes or productFlavors when uploadArchives?

Tags: android, maven

I now just use AndroidStudio,here is my problem:

I have a android library but there are many different environment,eg debug,test,and release,each of these environments relate a different request url,and i use maven to manage my library,each of environment relate a different maven url,i want use productFlavors to appoint different request url then build different aars and upload to maven,but i donot know how to select the specific buildType or productFlavors when uploadArchives,if there are any other ways to solve my problem,please help me,thanks!

Here is build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
    flavors_release {
        resValue("string", "url", "http://....")
    }
    flavors_dev {
        resValue("string", "url", "http://...")
    }
}
uploadArchives {
repositories.mavenDeployer {
    repository(url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/nexus/content/repositories/test/') {
        authentication(userName: "admin",
                password: "admin123")
    }
    pom.project {
        name 'mylibrary'
        packaging 'aar'
        description ''
        url 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/nexus/content/repositories/test/'
        groupId ""
        artifactId ''
        version ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Android used to use ANT in Eclipse and now in Android Studio, Gradle is used as management and build tool. never heard of anything about maven

Comment: I create a local repository in local area network by apply plugin 'maven',so i want to upload aars which is relate different request url when execute the uploadArchives command! Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve my problem,i defined a buildConfigField:boolean TEST in defaultConfig,so in my java code,i can select the request url by judge TEST,and i can also select the local repositories address by judge TEST.Of cause,these values can be defined in the local.properties as the form of key=value!

Answer (score -1):

I have Tried different type of builds using product flavors in android studio.
Ref Code:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "http://jzaccone.github.io/SlidingMenu-aar" }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.testandroid"  //your app id
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("/keystore/debug.keystore")
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storePassword 'android'
        }

        googlePlayRelease {
            storeFile file("/keystore/key.jks")
            keyAlias 'android'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storePassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true

        }


    }

    productFlavors {
        stagingBuild {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DEMO", "false"
        }

        demoBuild {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DEMO", "true"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'

}
```

You can select build type in **Build variant** to build the apk file.

Comment: Thanks!But how can i select the specific flavor when i upload to my local repository?And my project is a library,i need share my project to other develpers in my team,so i need a test environment to test my code which has a test request url,and also need a release environment to share my library which has a release request url.Of cause,i use the maven and nexus oss to manage my project!